# Python. Как изменить значения элементов управления Word?

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, python-docx

С помощью Python и библиотеки docx пытаюсь внести изменения в документ Word. В документе присутствуют элементы управления содержимым "форматированный текст" и "обычный текст", но при выводе содержимого всех параграфов:

```
text = []
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    text.append(paragraph.text)
print('\n'.join(text))
```

Python пропускает и вовсе не видит содержимого элементов управления Word. Соответственно и изменить я их не могу. Подскажите, как мне добраться и изменить содержимое элементов управления Word с помощью Python?

Comment: Вопрос слишком широкий. Именно про какой элемент управления вы тут спрашиваете?

Comment: @СергейКох меня интересует элемент управления содержимым "форматированныйтекст" или  элемент управления содержимым "обычный текст"

Answer (score 0):

`python-docx` до сих пор [не парсит](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/155) содержимое тегов* `w:sdt`, в которых находятся элементы управления содержимым, и не отдает их в "поверхностном" интерфейсе - то есть в содержании `paragraphs` и `runs`.

Но библиотека использует `lxml` для обработки документов и оставляет нам доступ к xml-структуре. Поэтому, следуя совету из тикета на гитхабе, мы, узнав* какие теги и в какой структуре используются нужными нам элементами, можем найти их с помощью `xpath` изменить их текст:

```
from docx import Document
doc = Document('sample_cc_file.docx')
doc_inner = doc._element
target_xpath = '//w:sdt//w:t'
for result_el in doc_inner.xpath(target_xpath):
    result_el.text = 'Мы заменили текст!'

doc.save('sample_cc_file 2.docx')
```

Полный xpath для нашего примера: `//w:sdt/w:sdtContent/w:p/w:r/w:t`.

Этот пример не охватывает все виды элементов управления содержимым. Для того, чтобы понять, какой xpath нам придется написать, нужно либо смотреть документацию ooxml, либо вручную смотреть на теги в нужных нам документах, о чем ниже. Исследуя новые для себя элементы, вас будет полезно очищать документы от всего лишнего, чтобы не тратить на поиски много времени.

---

* Поскольку все "новые" форматы файлов MS Office (docx, pptx) и другого ПО, использующего Office Open XML, это zip-архивы, содержащие определенную структуру xml-файлов, мы всегда можем вручную посмотреть, в каких тегах содержится нужная нам информация, будь то текст, картинки, и пр.: надо просто распаковать файл (например, с помощью 7-zip) и открыть нужную часть файла в текстовом редакторе. Обычно нужная нам информация содержится в `word/document.xml`.

Взаимодействовать программно с файлами ooxml можно с помощью `zipfile.ZipFile` и привычным для вас xml-парсером (`lxml`, `Beautiful Soup` и т.д.).

Comment: Большое спасибо, добрый человек

Comment: @Egor Если этот ответ вам помог, примите его, пожалуйста.